# Adaptive layouts in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, frame, geometryreader

I'm working on an iOS app that supports both iPhone and iPads. I have created the following layout in SwiftUI.

```swift
struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: geo.size.height * 0.03)
                
                Group {
                    Text("Welcome.Title")
                    Text("App.Name")
                }
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                Image(.dog)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.86, height: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .padding(.top, geo.size.height * 0.04)
                
                
                Text("Welcome.Message")
                    .font(.body)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.86)
                    .padding(.top, geo.size.height * 0.04)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Welcome.PrimaryButton.Title") {
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(.primary)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.86, height: geo.size.height * 0.068)
                .padding(.bottom)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Since it should support both iPhone and iPad screen sizes, I chose to define the dimensions for elements using the `GeometryReader`.

It looks nice on iPhone sizes.

[image: Layout on iPhones]

The problem is on iPads everything looks stretched out and huge!

[image: Layout on iPad]

I want to give sort of like a maximum value for dimensions only for iPads. For example, this is Facebook's login screen. The login form on iPad doesn't take up the entire width of the screen but it's not the same as the iPhone size as well.

[image: Example layouts]

Here's a rough mockup of the layout I'm trying to create for iPads. The best I can describe what I'm looking for is the elements shouldn't take up the entire width but at the same time, not having the same widths as on phone size. So sort of a middle ground.

[image: Mockup]

I tried fiddling with the minWidth/minHeight and maxWidth/maxHeight of `frame` modifier but no luck. How can I achieve something like this in SwiftUI?

Comment: Can you show a mockup of how you expected the dog book (not Facebook) to look on an iPad?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for the comment. It should look something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/RbOwcaX.jpeg). Elements have a wider width than on iPhones but not stretch too much on iPads.